# Autocomplete search when is result clicked value stay in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm modify this http://www.2lessons.info/2012/09/facebook-type-search-box-with-auto.html for my use, but i have one problem, i don't need link in result, but when i click on result value of result should stay in textbox (fill textbox with result value.). Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

My best sugesstion is to go for Jquery Auto Complete.  You can find here:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/   and also here

http://www.webappers.com/2013/01/25/jquery-auto-complete-auto-suggest-text-input/

Hope this helps..

Comment: How to to set source of jquery auto complete function to be results form mysql table?

Comment: @Thug..download.and check out the code. the results from database are obtained using Ajax calls..